# android hide keyboard method(error when focus lose)

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have some Fragments with EditTexts. When I write text in EditText on the first fragment I open next fragment. How can I hide the keyboard?

I am doing this:

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

but if i return on first fragment and again open next fragment focus lose. and i have error.

I found

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

But I have many fields on the fragment and many fragments with fields. I don't want duplicate code.

My error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.skip.client.customer.utils.Utils.hideSoftKeyboard(Utils.java:13)
            at com.skip.client.customer.fragments.auth_fragments.SignUpChooseTypeAuthFragment$EventHandler.onValidationSucceeded(SignUpChooseTypeAuthFragment.java:102)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.triggerValidationListenerCallback(Validator.java:673)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:651)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validateUnorderedFieldsWithCallbackTill(Validator.java:633)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:313)
            at com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator.validate(Validator.java:274)
            at com.skip.client.customer.fragments.auth_fragments.SignUpChooseTypeAuthFragment$EventHandler.onClick(SignUpChooseTypeAuthFragment.java:89)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7696791/3036759

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a `View` to your `hideSoftKeyboard` method and get a context from a `View`'s [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()).

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
        (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
```

Need to say passing an `Activity` around could be a bad idea because this may entail [memory leaks](http://www.curious-creature.com/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/comment-page-1/) which are hard to debug and fix.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, View view) {
          if(activity!= null && !activity.isFinish() && view != null) 
          {
             InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
private void hideSoftKeyBoard(ScrollView view){
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}
```

This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following working for me

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (null != activity.getWindow()){
    activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```